# Python Is sys.getsizeof return memory used by dynamic array too if argument is a list object

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management

List in python is implemented by dynamic array. So there is a pointer in list object that point to a array in heap. Source code is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c22476c01622f11b7745ee693f8b296a9d6a761/Include/listobject.h#L22).

```
typedef struct {
PyObject_VAR_HEAD
/* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
PyObject **ob_item;

/* ob_item contains space for 'allocated' elements.  The number
 * currently in use is ob_size.
 * Invariants:
 *     0 <= ob_size <= allocated
 *     len(list) == ob_size
 *     ob_item == NULL implies ob_size == allocated == 0
 * list.sort() temporarily sets allocated to -1 to detect mutations.
 *
 * Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
 * the list is not yet visible outside the function that builds it.
 */
Py_ssize_t allocated;
```

} PyListObject;

So I think that sys.getsizeof would return a constant value no matter how many items is in the list because the list object contains only one pointer, one MACRO(PyObject_HEAD Py_ssize_t ob_size;) and one integer.

However, I found that the return value of sys.getsizeof on list increased with the number of item in the list increased.

Example:

```
sys.getsizeof([])                         #returns 72
sys.getsizeof([1])                        #returns 80
sys.getsizeof([x for x in xrange(1024)])  #returns 9032
```

Why the return value of sys.getsizeof on list is not a constant value?

Comment: Objects can override their reported size by supplying a `.__sizeof__()` method; `list` does this, in order to account for the size of the separate block of memory holding the element references.  (The reported size would be *utterly useless* otherwise!)

Comment: @jasonharper, thanks, you solved my question.